# Why is VS Code highlighting syntax between underscores

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting

I fairly new to VS Code and there are many features that I already love. One thing that has been very distracting, however, is that any text between underscores is automatically highlighted as bold, white text. The issue seems to occur with any dark theme (but not light themes). Below, you can see the issue where two variables (`image_id` and `num_in_group`) create white text in between the underscores, and the same is true throughout my code.

[image]

Here you can see that the token identification of `image_id` is correct, meaning the white text does not relate to tokenization.

[image]

I don't know when the issue started, and therefore I have no idea if it started with a particular extension or setting change I made, or if it's always been there. I prefer dark themes as they are easier on my eyes, and I can't get away from using underscores in my code (e.g., many R `tidyverse` functions use underscores). I'm on MacOS running VS Code 1.78.2, and using it mostly for python and R. Where should I look to fix this issue?

I've tried multiple languages and the issue holds for python, R, and C++ (I haven't tested others). I've also tested numerous dark themes, and they all have the same issue. The same is true for high contrast themes, but does not seem to be an issue for light themes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem after installing VSCode extension 'R Markdown All in One' ([TianyiShi.rmarkdown](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TianyiShi.rmarkdown)) v0.0.14. Disabling the extension fixed the syntax highlighting issue.

Edit to add: this is documented in [Issue #21: Underscores mess up code highlighting](https://github.com/TianyiShi2001/rmarkdown-vscode/issues/21)

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! The issue disappeared for me a couple days after posting my original question. But since then I haven't opened any Rmd files until, just now after reading your comment, I created a new R Markdown script and the issue started up again for all my open files. Disabling the extension and restarting VS Code solved the issue.